# Why is an empty list not tested by VectorQ?

Tags: expression-test, language-design

I am a bit amazed by this behavior of [`VectorQ[ expr, test ]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorQ.html?q=VectorQ):

```
VectorQ[ {}, NumberQ ]
```

> True

It seems that the test itself is never applied and thus does not matter, so `NumericQ` or `OddQ` for example will also return `True`.

I find this behavior quite unfortunate, given that the documentation states:

> VectorQ[ expr, NumberQ] tests whether expr is a vector of numbers.

One might also note that `NumberQ[ Nothing ]` or `NumericQ[{}]` return `False` and that `NumberQ /@ {}` returns `{}`.

Is this a *bug* or a *feature* (true to mathematics)?

Comment: I guess it is applying the test as many times as there are elements of the list.  Since there are zero elements, it applies the test zero times.

Comment: @JasonB Yes, but then the description in the documentation is utterly misleading because the empty set/list is *not* a vector of numbers: `FreeQ[ {}, e_ /; NumberQ[e] ] (* True *)`.

Comment: This is exactly as it has to be. `VectorQ[list, test]` will only return `False` when there is an element in list for which the test fails. For an empty list, such an element does not exist, so the result will be `True`. (For the same reason, the statement "all elements of the empty set are green" is true.)

Comment: Relevant: `And[] (* True *)` and `Or[] (* False *)`

Comment: @Martin, it's in a similar vein to empty sums and products: it is reasonable to return the corresponding identity element in that case.

Comment: All great points and from some algebraic intuition (identity elements for multiplication (and) and addition (or) being different) this might very well make sense. But again: The empty set is *not* a vector of numbers, so if `VectorQ[ expr, NumberQ ]` were a test for that property as the documentation states, it must return `False`. There is precision in language. In other words: *The fact that all elements of the empty set are green is a true proposition does not make the empty set a set of green elements.* The description in the documentation then is simply false. Or? :)

Comment: @gwr I think it's valid in the sense that it's an empty vector of numbers. In other words, `VectorQ` tests whether your input is in $\mathbb{C}^n$, where $n$ is a non-negative integer. It's implementation seems to be essentially, `ListQ @ expr && And @@ test /@ expr`, which definitely makes the result (mathematically) consistent. You're right though that the documentation could be a bit clearer about that.

Comment: "The empty set is not a vector of numbers" <- but then the empty list is also not a list of non-numbers, and `VectorQ` is mostly used in conjunction with function argument patterns, to reject bad input. In practice it is *usually* more important what the function *shouldn't* accept than what it can accept.  Operations which work on lists of numbers *usually* (not always) generalize well for empty lists too. It makes sense to accept empty lists. I think that this is a useful feature.  If it didn't behave this way, many people (including me) would be complaining loudly.

Comment: Of course neither behaviour (return `True` or `False`) is convenient for *every* application, so sometimes we will need to handle edge cases manually.  But I think that this behaviour is the desired one for *the majority* of common applications.  For your application you may need to write a special pattern manually.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Others have argued in the comments that this behaviour makes sense mathematically, and I fully agree.  But further than that, it is also very practical.

Mathematica's functions are usually designed to give reasonable results for edge cases in the sense that if you put these functions together and write some more complex calculation, this compound function will also give sensible results for edge cases, without having to handle them manually.  What is a sensible result of course depends on the particular application.  In some cases it is unavoidable to manually handle edge cases.  But generally we want a behaviour which is practical in most common applications.

`VectorQ` is often used for checking function arguments.  For example,

```
f[vec_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ]&)] := vec + 1
```

Functions which operate on lists of numbers can *usually* be generalized for the empty list.  It would be very annoying if the empty list had to be handled manually.

This `f` function returns a new list where each element is incremented by 1.  If it works at all for an empty list, the only sensible result is another empty list.  This works automatically.

This sort of behaviour is common in Mathematica.  For example, `Total[{}]` gives `0` and so does `Sum[k, {k,{}}]`;  `Max[{}]` gives `-Infinity`; `{}*3` gives `{}`; and so on.  All these could alternatively throw errors, but that behaviour would not be as useful as the current one.  To be consistent with these, `VectorQ[{}, False&]` must be `True`.  These choices are not suitable for *every* application, but they try to be useful for *most applications*.  For the rest, we just need to handle edge cases manually.

I think that this behaviour is a very useful and practical *feature* from a programmer's point of view (even if we ignore mathematics completely).  It reduces the number of situations where edge cases need to be considered separately, so we can spend less time on coding.

Comment: Great answer, very well articulated. I am glad I did not write my own. +1.

Comment: This is a very reasonable and balanced answer, making it an easy accept. Such clarity would nicely become the documentation, which imo here is wanting. Note how `And[]` and `Or[]` are "hidden" in examples while a clear design principle is being followed.

Comment: Yes. Zero is a perfectly good number, and a zero length vector is a perfectly good vector. One minor instance where Mathematica falls down here is `Transpose`. Its model of tensor algebra does not distinguish between row and column vectors (good), but then sometimes I want to define a function that works on matrices, vectors, or scalars. I find that these things would generalize properly if `Transpose` of a vector or scalar simply yielded the vector or scalar. Of course, this isn't hard to fix with a custom function.