# How to draw a hanging rootogram in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, visualization

I am trying to plot a [hanging rootogram](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095919378) of some data in Mathematica. I can't seem to find a built in function for it, while simply using `Histogram` (on "transformed" data) does not seem to plot what I want.

Comment: By "a hanging rootogram" do you mean like the one shown [here](http://www.improving-visualisation.org/vis/id=257) ? If not, please change the link I put in your question to something more relevant.

Comment: "some data" - can you please show us this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
ClearAll[hangingRootogram]
hangingRootogram[dat_, estdist_, binspec_: Automatic][sc___ : .9, o: OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{hd = HistogramDistribution[dat, binspec], bins = HistogramList[dat, binspec][[1]]}, 
  With[{es = sc  Min@Differences@bins}, 
   DiscretePlot[{Sqrt@PDF[estdist, x] - Sqrt@PDF[hd, x], Sqrt@PDF[estdist, x]}, {x, bins}, 
    ExtentSize -> es, PlotMarkers -> {None, {"Point", Large}}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, o]]]
```

Examples:

```
data = RandomVariate[NegativeBinomialDistribution[10, 0.3], 10^2];
edist = EstimatedDistribution[data, NegativeBinomialDistribution[n, p], 
  ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"];

Row[{Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", ImageSize -> 400], 
  hangingRootogram[data, edist][.8, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
   FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.7], Blue, EdgeForm[{Blue, Thick}]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Row[hangingRootogram[data, EstimatedDistribution[data, #, 
      ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]][.8, ImageSize -> 400, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotLabel -> #, 
    FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.7], Blue, EdgeForm[{Blue, Thick}]], 
    PlotRange -> Full] & /@ 
   {NegativeBinomialDistribution[n, p], NegativeBinomialDistribution[n, .5],
    PoissonDistribution[n]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[5], 10^3];
edist = EstimatedDistribution[data, PoissonDistribution[n], 
  ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"];

Row[{Histogram[data, {3}, "PDF", ImageSize -> 400], 
  hangingRootogram[data, edist, {3}][.8, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
   FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.7], Blue, EdgeForm[{Blue, Thick}]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Probably the best solution so far (+1). I think it complements mine since it uses PDFs and use bin counts. Please consider overloading `hangingRootogram` to not take the distribution parameter `edist`.

Comment: So much from a compact function. One of the coolest answers I've seen in a while. +1

Comment: Thank you @ciao for the kind words and the upvote.

Answer (score 9):

The defined function `RootHistogram` makes a "hanging rootogram" more-or-less following [this definition](http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095919378).

The first argument is the data. The second argument `dist` is optional distribution. The function uses `SmoothHistogram` for the hanging curve and the third argument, `bandWidth`, is the band width argument of `SmoothHistogram`. The `bspec` argument is given to `HistogramList`.  The `sqRoot` argument is in adherence to [the mentioned definition](http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095919378):

> [...] As in the rootogram, the vertical axis is scaled to the square-root of
>   the frequencies so as to draw attention to discrepancies in the tails
>   of the distribution.

```
Clear[RootHistogram]
RootHistogram[data : {_?NumberQ ..}, dist_: Automatic, 
   bandWidth_: "StandardDeviation", bspec_: Automatic, 
   sqRoot : (True | False) : True, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Block[{gr, shpoints, nf, x0, x1, s, xs, ds, ps},
   gr = SmoothHistogram[data, bandWidth, "Intensity"];
   shpoints = 
    SortBy[Cases[gr[[1]], Line[p_] :> p, \[Infinity]][[1]], First];
   If[! TrueQ[dist === Automatic],
    ds = Table[PDF[dist, x], {x, shpoints[[All, 1]]}];
    ds = Rescale[ds, MinMax[ds], MinMax[shpoints[[All, 2]]]];
    shpoints[[All, 2]] = ds
    ];
   If[sqRoot, shpoints[[All, 2]] = Sqrt[shpoints[[All, 2]]]];
   nf = Nearest[shpoints[[All, 1]] -> Automatic];
   {x0, x1} = MinMax[data];
   ps = HistogramList[data, bspec];
   ps = Transpose[{Mean /@ Partition[ps[[1]], 2, 1], ps[[2]]}];
   If[sqRoot, ps[[All, 2]] = Sqrt[ps[[All, 2]]]];
   s = Max[Abs[Differences[ps[[All, 1]]]]];
   Graphics[{
     GrayLevel[0.7],
     Map[Rectangle[{#[[1]] - s/2.5, 
         shpoints[[nf[#[[1]]][[1]], 2]] - #[[2]]}, {#[[1]] + s/2.5, 
         shpoints[[nf[#[[1]]][[1]], 2]]}] &, ps],
     Blue, Line[Select[shpoints, x0 <= #[[1]] <= x1 &]],
     Red, Point[Map[shpoints[[nf[#[[1]]][[1]]]] &, ps]]}, opts, 
    Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
   ];

dist = PoissonDistribution[8];
data = RandomVariate[dist, 500];

opts = {ImageSize -> 450, Axes -> False, Frame -> True};
Grid[{{Histogram[data, 20, PlotLabel -> "Histogram", opts],
   RootHistogram[data, Automatic, "StandardDeviation", 20, True, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(SmoothHistogram\)]\) with hanging \
\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(HistogramList\)]\) panels", opts]},
  {RootHistogram[data, Automatic, "StandardDeviation", 20, False, 
    PlotLabel -> "SmoothHistogram with hanging HistogramList panels", opts],
   RootHistogram[data, NormalDistribution[11, 2],"StandardDeviation", 20, True, PlotLabel -> 
     "\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(Max[SmoothHistogram] PDF[N[11, 2], x]\)]\) with \
hanging \!\(\*SqrtBox[\(HistogramList\)]\) panels", opts]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think the best way to answer this would be to look up Tukey's description in EDA. I'd check myself, but I'm far away from my copy. :(

Comment: @J.M. Yeah, it would be nice to read that article...

Comment: I noticed `{_?NumberQ..}` here.  You may be interested in this chat from yesterday: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30840228#30840228

Comment: @Szabolcs related to your comment: [(8652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8652/121), [(16694)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16694/121), [(49331)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49331/121), [(111438)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111438/121)

Comment: Aha, [found it](https://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/tukey)! It wasn't in EDA after all, upon checking my copy.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot, much appreciated! I have seen some of Edward Tufte's writings, I did not know about [his website](https://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/).

Comment: Just to be clear, that was Tukey's article; Tufte merely reposted it on his website as an example of his crusade of making informative pictures, of which Tukey has made contributions.

Comment: @J.M. Right it is Tukey's. The article can be also found in the book ["The Collected Works of John W. Tukey: Graphics 1965-1985, Volume 5"](https://books.google.com/books?id=z_F5Tyt66c0C&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%22some+graphic+and+semigraphic+displays%22&source=bl&ots=k3kYhKwkNc&sig=b29NvmsffhVtqEGCLNMhCmN_uYc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqpfGirOvNAhVD4iYKHVJKC_wQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%22some%20graphic%20and%20semigraphic%20displays%22&f=false).

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to interprete scaling of frequencies and associated expected curve so I will just plot PDF. This answer isn't complete then!

Here is a simple way to hang those bars using `ChartElementFunction`:

```
d = NormalDistribution[0, 1]
n = 100
data = RandomVariate[d, n];
bspec = {-5, 5, .5};

 f[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] :=  Module[{
     m = Mean@{xmin, xmax}, yMax
     }, 
     yMax = PDF[d, m];
     {
       Opacity@.5, 
       Translate[Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}], {0, yMax - ymax}],
       AbsolutePointSize@7, Red, 
       Point[{m, yMax}]
     }
];


Show[
 Plot[ PDF[d, x], {x, #, #2}] & @@ bspec,(*expected*)
 Histogram[data, bspec, (*experimental*) 
    "PDF", 
    ChartElementFunction -> f
 ],
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {{}, {0}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Thick
]
```

[image]

Of course the more points the better match:

```
n = 10000
```

[image]

Comment: I think this does not work with well with other distributions like `PoissonDistribution` or `WeibullDistribution`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks for attention, I will try to investigate later, have to go now.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Seems to work well with Weibull.  Poisson is a discrete distribution so neither Plot nor a non-integer binned histogram would be appropriate.

Comment: @Szabolcs Please see my answer -- it has graphs/histograms with `PoissonDistribution`.

Comment: @Anton Yes, but yours simply does something different.  It uses SmoothHistogram.  Kuba uses PDF.  That would require special handling for discrete distributions (which don't technically have a probability *density*).  I don't think the two approaches are comparable in a work / doesn't work way.  They do different things.

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree the approaches are complementary. My first comment to this answer was because of the examples I have seen of "rootogram" -- they use bin counts and Poisson distribution, like [this one](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/man/rootogram.html).

Comment: @AntonAntonov I see the case is clear now thanks to Szabolcs, yes it is not very general answer but since yours and and kglr's cover so much I don't think I find motivation/reason to extend it soon :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a much simpler approach than already given and simply takes theoretical and measured values:

```
rootogram[theory_, observations_] := Show[{
   ListLinePlot[{theory}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}],
   Graphics[{Table[
      Line[{{i, theory[[i]]}, {i, 
         measurements[[i]] - theory[[i]]}}], {i, Length[theory]}]}]
   }]

theory = {3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21};
measurements = {2, 4, 7, 10, 12, 10, 16, 18, 19, 20};
rootogram[theory, measurements]
```

[image]